# How to go about making vertical ticker in silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I have a list of items that I want to slowly scroll vertically until the mouse is hovered over the list of items. Then, a scroll bar will appear. The part that I am stuck on is the best way to have the effect of the list constantly looping over. So if you have:

```
-----
A
B
C
D
E
-----
```

it will scroll and look something like this:

```
----
D
E
A
B
C
----
```

Is there a way for me to do this without having two collections?

Comment: Perhaps something like this will help you? [wp7 looping selector](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/wp7-looping-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    ObservableCollection<string> myList;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        myList.Add("A");
        myList.Add("B");
        myList.Add("C");
        myList.Add("D");
        myList.Add("E");

        System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(TimerFired));
        t.Change(500, 500);

        listBox2.ItemsSource = myList ;          
    }

    private void TimerFired(object sender)
    {
        Pop();
    }
    private delegate void PopDelegate();
    private void Pop()
    {
        if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            string item = myList[myList.Count - 1];
            myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count - 1);
            myList.Insert(0, item);

        }
        else
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new PopDelegate(Pop), null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Looking at your code, instead of scrolling you are just reordering the list essentially. However, I am trying to do a more fluid motion of scrolling. Thanks, though.